# Using countifs with case sensitive

Tags: excel

I'm using this formula to get cell contains A3 and "B"

> =IF(COUNTIFS('rekap per file'!$D:$D,$A3&"*",'rekap per file'!$D:$D,"*B*")>0,1,"")

But the formula keep capture text with "b" as the result. How can I only get the cell with "B" without capture "b" using the formula in excel? Thanks

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/396431-case-sensitive-countif.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using countif you can use the below formula which will give the case-sensitive value.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--EXACT("B",A1:A9)))
```